# Post awaiting review notification bug

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

This bug has been there ever since I reached a 10K reputation:

[image]

Near review, there is always this orange box with a number on it often saying "X total posts awaiting review" when you hover over on it. That isn't the problem, the problem is that there are no posts awaiting review, once I click:

[image]

Wondering if that happens too with other members. I never had this problem when I had low reputation, only when my reputation increased to above 10K.

This is not normal because if there are no posts to review, the website shouldn't show 9 total posts awaiting review.

Any help from software engineers who work for SE?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230742/notification-for-reviews-shows-way-too-much